# How can you keep a Geometry Nodes displaced plane's edges at location 0 on the Z axis?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, displacement, vertex-groups

So, within a *Geometry Nodes* setup I'm using a noise texture to create a procedural landscape on a Grid Primitive as explained in many YouTube videos.

The node tree I use works by using the noise texture fed into the *Offset* socket on a *Set Position* node (various other nodes in the node tree e.g. *Math* nodes etc).

I'm trying to figure out how to select the perimeter of the Grid Primitive and prevent it from moving on the Z axis i.e. pin the perimeter down using the *Geometry Nodes* setup. It would be even better if I could apply some sort of adjustable falloff from the perimeter edges etc.?

I can't find anything at all to help me with this?

Comment: You should provide at least a picture of your set up. There are usually several ways to do things and people won't know which one you are using without it

Comment: Thanks, that's a fair comment. Some people have been very kind in still providing some really good feedback and solutions though.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **edge neighbors** node to select inside faces of mesh, not the border.
[image]

[image]
(blender 3.6.1)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is much appreciated. I will take a look at this again now.

Answer (score 2):

You have several possibilities here...

One possibility would be to combine the noise texture with a gradient texture, and to define its effect and range with `Map Range`:

[image]

Another possibility would be, if you really need the exact distance to the outer edges, to combine this distance with the noise texture using `Geometry Proximity`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is much appreciated. I will take a look at this again now.

Comment: By accident I noticed that you'd built a Node Group called "ProximityAndProjectGN" in your example file. Can you please tell me how and what are you using this for, as I'm interested in this?

Comment: @Googey1 Uh, no, I did not create a node group with that label in this file. I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you mean by that... Could you please explain it in more detail?